# Is there a way to /give an arctic fox spawn egg in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a command to /give myself an arctic fox spawn egg?

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

```
/give @s fox_spawn_egg{tag:{EntityTag:{Type:snow}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the command that should work for the Java edition:

```
/give @p fox_spawn_egg{EntityTag:{id:"Fox",Type:"snow"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
summon minecraft:fox ~ ~ ~ {Type:"snow"}
```

This wont give you a spawn egg, but it will spawn the Arctic fox right in front of your eyes.