# How do you tp to the nearest Arctic Fox?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to tp to the nearest fox regardless of what type it is. It would be performed via the following command:

```
/tp @s @e[type=fox,sort=nearest,limit=1]
```

However, I was wondering how would you specify that the mob you are typing to *must* be an arctic fox? I tried implementing what [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359452/is-there-a-way-to-give-an-arctic-fox-spawn-egg-in-minecraft) was talking about with adding nbt data to it. So I tried the following command:

```
/tp @s @e[type=fox,nbt={tag:{EntityTag:{Type:snow}}},sort=nearest,limit=1]
```

But it still didn't seem to work and error out. Could someone give me a correct command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity tags when referring to actual entities should just be in the root tag, not in any subtags.

Additionally, `minecraft:` is required when testing for NBT data that has it.

With those issues fixed, the fixed selector looks like this:

```
@e[type=minecraft:fox,nbt={Type:"minecraft:snow"}]
```